# how do I list the next few weeks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, week-number

I am trying to list the next 10 weeks

The result should be like this:

```
Week        Year
----------------
45:         2012  
46:         2012  
47:         2012  
48:         2012  
49:         2012  
50:         2012  
51:         2012  
52:         2012  
1:          2013  
2:          2013
```

some years there is a week 53, and this year the 31st of December is on a Monday, is this week 1 or week 53??

Anyways, I want to skip week 53, whenever it occours. This means that 1 or 2 days will not be a part of any week on the list, but this doesn't matter.

Comment: What part of this are you having issues with? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just wrote a small console app that does just that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //Use current date as starting point
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            int weekNo = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
            dt,
            ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
            ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
             );
            int year = ci.Calendar.GetYear(dt);
            if (weekNo == 53) //if week number==53, then go to next week
            {
                dt = dt.AddDays(7);
                weekNo = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                dt,
                ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
                 );
                year = ci.Calendar.GetYear(dt);
            }

            dt = dt.AddDays(7);
            Console.WriteLine(weekNo + "-" + year);
        }
    }
```

output today:

```
    46-2012
    47-2012
    48-2012
    49-2012
    50-2012
    51-2012
    52-2012
    1-2013
    2-2013
    3-2013
```

Answer (score 2):

> some years there is a week 53, and this year the 31st of December is on a Monday, is this week 1 or week 53??

Assuming you mean "week of week-year", that would be week 1 of week-year 2013.

In the ISO calendar, the first week of a week-year is the first Monday-Sunday week which has 4 days or more in it.

It's not clear why you'd want to skip week 53 - it doesn't just skip 1 or 2 days, it skips a whole week.

Of course, this really is assuming you mean the ISO definition of "week of year". If you don't, it's a different matter. You need to clarify your requirements before you do anything else.

To obtain the week-of-week-year from .NET, you can use [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) - for the ISO definition you'd use `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` and `DayOfWeek.Monday`. I don't know whether there's anything to get the week-year itself though.

As a blatant plug, in my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) there's support for both `WeekYear` and `WeekOfWeekYear` on dates, and you can construct a date for a given week-year/week-of-week-year/day-of-week combination.

Comment: I thought week 53 would at most consist of 2 days, in which case I wouldn't need it on the list... but nevermind, might as well have it there regardless of the length.

Answer (score 0):

from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
      Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

      Console.WriteLine("{0:d}: Week {1} ({2})", date1, 
                        cal.GetWeekOfYear(date1, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                          dfi.FirstDayOfWeek),
                        cal.ToString().Substring(cal.ToString().LastIndexOf(".") + 1));       
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: //       1/1/2011: Week 1 (GregorianCalendar)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will work based off of the number of weeks since the start of the year.

if you want this to be based off of full weeks then you'll need to determine an offset of 0 or 1 at the start based on the day of the first week of the year.

```
public class Week
{
    public Week(int weekOfYear, int year)
    {
        WeekOfYear = weekOfYear;
        Year = year;
    }
    public int WeekOfYear { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }
}
public IEnumerable<Week> Next10Weeks(DateTime startDate)
{
    DateTime tempDate = startDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //add one to first parameter if you want the 1-indexed week instead of 0 indexed
        yield return new Week(tempDate.DayOfYear % 7, tempDate.Year);
        tempDate.AddDays(7);
    }
}
```